# C# WebBrowser Control Download (Without Prompt + Certificate SSL + WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webbrowser-control, ssl-certificate

The problem:

1. Capture all the ASP.NET VIEWSTATE POSTBACK DATA
2. Simulate the Session/Cookie state of your WebBrowser in a SSLEnabled-WebClient
3. Send The WebForm POSTDATA thru SSLEnabled-WebClient to automatically Download the File
4. Manage the File

Digging for any solution to my complex problem, finally I found a solution.

Comment: You found a solution? Then you should post it as an answer. And probably clean the question up

Comment: You came quicker than I. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add reference to MSHTML to your project
   `c:\windows\system32 or WOW64\mshtml.dll`
2. Using `JQuery.serialize()` I could manage to get the FormData from Top ASP.NET Form.

   2.1 Appending Jquery Library to your WebBrowser CurrentPage

   ```
   HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   HtmlElement scriptEl1 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
   scriptEl1.SetAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js");
   head.AppendChild(scriptEl1);
   ```

   2.2 Create a new div HTML Element that receive the postData by scripting

   ```
   HtmlElement scriptEl2 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
   mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl2.DomElement;
   element.text = @"
   function CreatePostData() { 
        //alert('Jquery online');
        var postData = jQuery(document.forms[0]).serialize();
        var divPost = document.createElement(""DIV"");
        divPost.innerText = postData;
        divPost.id = ""divPost"";
        document.body.appendChild(divPost);
        //alert(divPost.innerText);
   }";

   head.AppendChild(scriptEl2);

   webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("CreatePostData");
   string postData = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("divPost").InnerText;
   ```
3. Once you have the PostData, you now need a WebClient SSLSecure Enabled

   ```
   class SecureWebClient : WebClient
   {
       protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
       {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
           string certPath = @"C:\TEMP\ClientCertificateFile.cer";
           X509Certificate myCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);
           request.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);
           return request;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now you have to syncronize the same WebBrowser state with WebClient's, some websites/systems use HTTPOnly cookies for that and that was my case. Those cookies don't come by default in WebBrowser `Document.Cookie` property, to overcome call for

   ```
    var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(webBrowser1.Url, false);`
   ```

   If you need to use HTTPOnly cookies as above, add another class to your project:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Net;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using System.Security;
   using System.Security.Permissions;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   internal sealed class NativeMethods
   {
   #region enums

   public enum ErrorFlags
   {
       ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122,
       ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
       ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
   }

   public enum InternetFlags
   {
       INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192, //Requires IE 8 or higher   
       INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY = 131072,
       INTERNET_FLAG_RESTRICTED_ZONE = 16
   }

   #endregion

   #region DLL Imports

   [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, SecurityCritical, DllImport("wininet.dll", EntryPoint = "InternetGetCookieExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
   internal static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx([In] string Url, [In] string cookieName, [Out] StringBuilder cookieData, [In, Out] ref uint pchCookieData, uint flags, IntPtr reserved);

       #endregion
   }


   /// <SUMMARY></SUMMARY>   
   /// WebBrowserCookie?   
   /// webBrowser1.Document.CookieHttpOnlyCookie   
   ///    
   public class FullWebBrowserCookie : WebBrowser
   {

   [SecurityCritical]
   public static string GetCookieInternal(Uri uri, bool throwIfNoCookie)
   {
       uint pchCookieData = 0;
       string url = UriToString(uri);
       uint flag = (uint)NativeMethods.InternetFlags.INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY;

       //Gets the size of the string builder   
       if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, null, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
       {
           pchCookieData++;
           StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)pchCookieData);

           //Read the cookie   
           if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, cookieData, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
           {
               DemandWebPermission(uri);
               return cookieData.ToString();
           }
       }

       int lastErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

       if (throwIfNoCookie || (lastErrorCode != (int)NativeMethods.ErrorFlags.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS))
       {
           throw new Win32Exception(lastErrorCode);
       }

       return null;
   }

   private static void DemandWebPermission(Uri uri)
   {
       string uriString = UriToString(uri);

       if (uri.IsFile)
       {
           string localPath = uri.LocalPath;
           new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, localPath).Demand();
       }
       else
       {
           new WebPermission(NetworkAccess.Connect, uriString).Demand();
       }
   }

   private static string UriToString(Uri uri)
   {
       if (uri == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
       }

       UriComponents components = (uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? UriComponents.AbsoluteUri : UriComponents.SerializationInfoString);
       return new StringBuilder(uri.GetComponents(components, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped), 2083).ToString();
   }   }
   ```
5. Syncronize the WebControl State with WebClient, issue the PostData and capture the returning byteArray:

   ```
   SecureWebClient wc = new SecureWebClient();
   wc.Headers.Add("Cookie: " + cookies);
   wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   byte[] result = wc.UploadData("<URL>", "POST", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
   File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\<FileName>", result);
   wc.Dispose();
   ```